# "Invalid column name" thrown inside unreachable script block

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a large sql script designed so that it is 'safe' to run on different instances, or on the same instance multiple times without causing any bad data or errors

When writing such scripts I have always depended on syntax like:

```
if not exists (select 1 from SYS.FOREIGN_KEYS where NAME = 'FK_BAR')
begin
  alter table [MyTable]
    add constraint FK_BAR foreign key (some_id) references Other_Table(some_id)
end
go
```

This usually works pretty well.  However, I recently encountered a scenario where I am unable to prevent errors from being thrown during execution.  In the below code, the column "deprecated_column" has been dropped from table Foo:

```
if     exists (select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'Foo' and COLUMN_NAME = 'deprecated_column')
   and exists (select 1 from [Foo] where new_column is null)
begin
    declare @updated int set @updated = 1;

    while @updated > 0
    begin
        update top (500000)
               Foo
           set new_column = deprecated_column
         where new_column is null
        ;
        set @updated = @@rowcount;
    end
end
go
```

If I run the two `exist`'s within the `if` independently of this program, they return "no results" as expected, which means the inner code will never be executed.  However, when I run the script, the server throws the error: `Invalid column name 'deprecated_column'.`, and the script is marked as completing with error, which causes an alert to be raised on our system (ie, the DBA is notified and has to check), which is causing some unnecessary overhead on what should be a simple automated task.

Is there some syntax that I have overlooked that would allow this code to run without error in all cases?

Comment: @SeanLange this is just not true what you have just said, put in any valid sql inside the IF block and if the control never enters the block there will be no exception.

Comment: @M.Ali you are correct...deleting my comment. :(

Comment: There is a challenge here for sure. If the table being referenced doesn't exist the code will compile correctly. If however the table does exist then it also checks for the existence of the column being referenced. IIRC this is part of deferred name resolution.

Comment: I think your error is reproducible in the case of multiple schemas, each containing a table named `Foo`.  Could this be the case?

Comment: Well, SQL Server checks that the code parses without checking if the `IF` conditions are met. You can workaround this by using dynamic SQL in the `UPDATE`. As in `SET @sql = 'update .....'` and then execute it

Comment: T-SQL is a *compiled* language and "Invalid Column" is a compiler error, not an execution error.  However, since most T-SQL is only compiled right before execution, that's when you usually see it.  The only immediate way around this is with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained in the comments, T-SQL is a compiled language and "Invalid Column" is a compiler error, not an execution error.  However, since most T-SQL is only compiled right before execution, that's when you usually see it.

Since T-SQL tries to compile all of the code regardless of IF branches, the only immediate way around this is with dynamic SQL.  Like so:

```
if     exists (select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'Foo' and COLUMN_NAME = 'deprecated_column')
   and exists (select 1 from [Foo] where new_column is null)
begin
    EXEC('
        declare @updated int set @updated = 1;

        while @updated > 0
        begin
            update top (500000)
                   Foo
               set new_column = deprecated_column
             where new_column is null
            ;
            set @updated = @@rowcount;
        end
    ');
end
go
```